# Android SOAP Object reference set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

I need to use SOAP instead of REST. So far, i followed SOAP and kSOAP2 tutorials and threads here and youtube.

This is the web service for getting request key. I completed this without any errors. I add RequestValid and current time with Time format: **“dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm”** and retrieve a request key(auth token) valid for the current minute.

URL : http://mobileexam.veripark.com/mobileforeks/service.asmx

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Encrypt xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <request>RequestIsValid29:01:2015 16:31</request>
    </Encrypt>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <EncryptResponse 
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <EncryptResult>%%UmVxdWVzdElzVmFsaWQyOTowMToyMDE1IDE2OjMx%%</EncryptResult>
        </EncryptResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I only add necessary code to retrieve request key.

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://mobileexam.veripark.com/mobileforeks/service.asmx";
private static final String METHOD_NAME_ENCRYPT = "Encrypt";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION_ENCRYPT = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME_ENCRYPT;

public void getRequestKey() {
    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_ENCRYPT);
    soapObject.addProperty("request", "RequestIsValid10:03:2018 16:30");
}
```

Next, using request key i need to get data but i can't understand the format of web service and correct properties i guess.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo>
         <tem:request>
            <tem:IsIPAD>true</tem:IsIPAD>
            <tem:DeviceID>test</tem:DeviceID>
            <tem:DeviceType>ipad</tem:DeviceType>
            <tem:RequestKey>%%UmVxdWVzdElzVmFsaWQxNjowNToyMDEyIDExOjU4%%</tem:RequestKey>
            <tem:Period>Month</tem:Period>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is something wrong when  tag encapsulates properties instead of being primitives. Adding properties directly is obviously not correct.

```
    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_FOREX);
    soapObject.addProperty("IsIPAD", "true");
    soapObject.addProperty("DeviceID", "test");
    soapObject.addProperty("DeviceType", "ipad");
    soapObject.addProperty("RequestKey", requestKey);
    soapObject.addProperty("Period", "Month");
```

Returns `Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I also tried adding properties, using a `KvmSerializable` class adding property with `PropertyInfo` but nothing works.

I would be grateful if you can provide a working example for this service.